# angularjs JavaScript inheritance, fail to bind data from view to a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

what am trying to do is to get data from the form use it in my controller in `HTTP` post call but it's not working

I know i might have problem with inheritance of scopes but icant solve it.
here is my controller code:

```
.controller('SignUpCtrl', function($scope, $http, $state) {  
 $scope.submit = function() {

   var url = 'http://localhost:3000/register';
   var user = {
        email: $scope.email,
        password: $scope.password,
      };
     console.log($scope.user);
   $http.post(url, user)
     .success(function(res){
        console.log('You are now Registered');
        //$state.go('app.items');
    })
     .error(function(err){
        console.log('Could not register');
         //  $state.go('error');
    });

  };

})
```

Here is the code of my Template:

```
   <form name="register">
        <div class="list">
            <label class="item item-input no-border">
                <input name="fullname" type="text" ng-model="fullname" placeholder="Full Name" required="">
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
                <input name="email" type="email" ng-model="user.email" placeholder="Email" required="">
            </label>
            <p class="blue-font" ng-show="register.email.$dirty && register.email.$invalid">Please Write valid Email.</p>
            <label class="item item-input">
                <input name="password" type="password" ng-model="user.password" placeholder="Password" required="">
            </label>
            <button ng-click="submit();" ng-disabled="register.$invalid" type="submit" class="button signup-btn sharb-border white-font blue-bg-alt border-blue-alt ">
                Sign Up
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Note: i tried the ng-submit its not really the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the controller.

```
    .controller('SignUpCtrl', function($scope, $http, $state) {
      $scope.user = {
        email: '',
        password: ''
      };
      $scope.submit = function() {
```

And this

```
    var user = {
      email: $scope.user.email,
      password: $scope.user.password
    };
```

Also drop the `;` in `ng-click`

```
    <button ng-click="submit()" ...>
```

Comment: when i did it this way i got TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined

Comment: That means that there is no `user` object in the `$scope`. I will edit the answer

Comment: Yes the problem was i had it inside the Submit function.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use rootScope ([docs.angularjs.org/$rootScope"](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope)).